# Issue with Tkinter Radio Buttons

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Can anyone hint me as to what I may be doing wrong here:

I'm trying to control one button's state using the state value from radio button i.e. if the **RadioButton1** is selected then disable the **Browse** button else if **RadioButton2** is selected then enable the **Browse** button. Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('175x100')
root.title('GUI App')
root.resizable(0,0)

def selection_0():
    val = var1.get()
    if (str(val) == '0'):
       print 'selection_0'
       browseButton = Button(root, text="Browse", relief = 'raised', width=8, command=fun1, cursor='hand2', state=DISABLED).place(x=50,y=50)
       radio_btn_state0 = ACTIVE
       radio_btn_state1 = NORMAL

def selection_1():
    val = var2.get()
    if (str(val) == '1'):
       print 'selection_1'  
       browseButton = Button(root, text="Browse", relief = 'raised', width=8, command=fun1, cursor='hand2', state=ACTIVE).place(x=50,y=50)
       radio_btn_state1 = ACTIVE
       radio_btn_state0 = NORMAL
def fun1():
   pass

radio_btn_state0 = NORMAL
radio_btn_state1 = NORMAL

var1 = StringVar()
RadioButton1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Selection 1", variable=var1,   value="0", command=selection_0, state=radio_btn_state0)
RadioButton1.place(x=2,y=10)

var2 = StringVar()
RadioButton2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Selection 2", variable=var2, value="1", command=selection_1,state=radio_btn_state1)
RadioButton2.place(x=82,y=10)

#Create the 'Browse' button
browseButton = Button(root, text="Browse", relief = 'raised', width=8,    command=fun1, cursor='hand2', state=DISABLED).place(x=50,y=50)

root.mainloop()
```

But I'm facing two issues here:

1. Both the radio buttons are coming selected by default when I run the program even though I haven't given anyone of them as active in the start of program. I need only one of them as active by default.
2. Even after controlling the state of **Browse** button, it is not getting disabled.

[image]

**EDIT:**Issue 2 resolved. The button has to be re-drawn at every selection of radio button as shown in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

First problem was occuring because I was using separate variables for each radio button i.e. var1 and var2 which was not grouping them in the same group. The solution is to use the same variable for both the radio buttons something like this:

```
var = IntVar()
RadioButton1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Selection 1", variable=var, value="1", command=selection_0).place(x=2,y=10)
RadioButton2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Selection 2", variable=var, value="2", command=selection_1).place(x=82,y=10)
```